# Australia Tourist Visa 600 "Evidence of Tourism" when visiting family member

Tags: australia, tourist-visas

I am applying Tourist Visa for Australia subclass 600, and on their attachment section they require me to attach "Evidence of Tourism in Australia". I am an Indonesian passport holder.

I'm planning to visit my sister (Who has Australian Permanent Residence visa) for a month for just family gathering and maybe helping her with daily activities since she's due to have a baby. I will be staying at her house, so I won't be booking any hotels/accommodation. What would be a good document to attach as Evidence of Tourism? I don't have flight tickets booked yet since it was recommended to book flights after securing the visa.

Comment: A letter of invitation from your sister confirming she’s providing your accommodation etc? Or maybe you should select ‘visiting family’ as the reason for your visit?

Comment: The Invitation letter from family is another document section that I can upload to, so that's why I'm a bit confused, should I put that invitation letter on both section? I did put visiting family on the reason section.